# Does ingress controller not require cert? for performing https

Tags: azure, https, certificate, self-signed-certificate

We have a http service running behind ingress controller(Azure).

Client send GET/POST request to ingress controller.

Ingress controller speaks https protocol.

Client is able to talk to http service(GET/POST requests) without a certificate(for TLS handshake)

https url of azure controller has certificate chain which is self-signed

---

Does client need certificate stored locally(to trust) to perform TLS handshake?